# Unable to install Flask-Mail

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, flask, version

I am trying to send an email using Flask when a user registers on my website. I used the command `pip install Flask-Mail` to install. However, I get the following error of possible version mismatch:

```
  Downloading/unpacking Flask-mail
  Downloading Flask-Mail-0.9.1.tar.gz (45kB): 45kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/Flask-mail/setup.py) egg_info for package Flask-mail
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/Flask-mail/setup.py", line 52, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules'
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 257, in finalize_options
        ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in require
        working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 592, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
    pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (certifi 2016.2.28 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('certifi==2015.11.20'))
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/Flask-mail/setup.py", line 52, in <module>

    'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules'

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__

    _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__

    self.finalize_options()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 257, in finalize_options

    ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in require

    working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 592, in resolve

    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here

pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (certifi 2016.2.28 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('certifi==2015.11.20'))

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/Flask-mail
```

Any possible workarounds? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My flask version is 0.10

Comment: check if you have certifi  ` pip freeze | grep certifi `

Comment: I do have it @SayedZainulAbideen

Comment: try upgrading certifi ` pip install --upgrade certifi
`

Comment: I upgraded it. Still giving same error.

Comment: please share a complete stack trace what u installed and when this error came it will be more helpfull

Comment: @SayedZainulAbideen Please have a look now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to avoid these kind of problems is to create a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

```
>>>pip install virtualenv

>>>cd my_project_folder
>>>virtualenv venv
```

now activate your virtual environment

```
>>>source venv/bin/activate
```

now install there `pip install Flask-Mail` 
hopefully now it should work there

if your done working then deactivate it

```
 >>>deactivate
```

## or

It seems like all the problem is because of `certifi` version conflict

so try downloading the source from here
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi

and install from source

Extract it go into the folder and run this command

```
sudo python setup.py  install
```

and it should work

peace

Comment: @Abhijay feel free to appreciate if it helped you or you gained some insights

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have virtual env set up I would suggest do so first. If you have that already you may need to activate that from your terminal:

`>>>source venv/bin/activate`

Once completed just deactivate it for your rest of the commands:

```
>>>deactivate
```